# Rails Raw SQL WHERE clause

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm making raw sql queries into my PG database in Rails. When I use only one date condition in the WHERE clause works perfectly, but when I use 2 date conditions it doesn't work as expected. To view the results I do a for each through the results object and print it to console.

With only one condition:

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection()
results = connection.execute("SELECT * 
                              FROM training_employees 
                              LEFT JOIN trainings 
                              ON training_employees.training_id = trainings.id 
                              WHERE trainings.date >='2014-06-29'")
results.each do |row|
  puts row
end
```

returns

```
{"id"=>"1", "employee_id"=>"2", "training_id"=>"1", 
 "created_at"=>"2014-06-29 06:44:13.261074", 
 "updated_at"=>"2014-06-29 06:44:13.261074", 
 "name"=>"Incendios", "date"=>"2014-06-30 02:43:00", 
 "expected_attendance"=>"20", "service_company_id"=>"1"}
{"id"=>"1", "employee_id"=>"3", "training_id"=>"1", 
 "created_at"=>"2014-06-29 06:44:13.261074", 
 "updated_at"=>"2014-06-29 06:44:13.261074", 
 "name"=>"Incendios", 
 "date"=>"2014-06-30 02:43:00", 
 "expected_attendance"=>"20", "service_company_id"=>"1"}
{"id"=>"1", "employee_id"=>"7", "training_id"=>"1", 
 "created_at"=>"2014-06-29 06:44:13.261074", 
 "updated_at"=>"2014-06-29 06:44:13.261074", 
 "name"=>"Incendios", "date"=>"2014-06-30 02:43:00", 
 "expected_attendance"=>"20", "service_company_id"=>"1"}
{"id"=>"1", "employee_id"=>"9", "training_id"=>"1", 
 "created_at"=>"2014-06-29 06:44:13.261074", 
 "updated_at"=>"2014-06-29 06:44:13.261074", 
 "name"=>"Incendios", "date"=>"2014-06-30 02:43:00", 
 "expected_attendance"=>"20", "service_company_id"=>"1"}
{"id"=>"1", "employee_id"=>"10", "training_id"=>"1", 
 "created_at"=>"2014-06-29 06:44:13.261074", 
 "updated_at"=>"2014-06-29 06:44:13.261074", 
 "name"=>"Incendios", "date"=>"2014-06-30 02:43:00", 
 "expected_attendance"=>"20", "service_company_id"=>"1"}
=> #<PG::Result:0x007fa8b9cfc038 
@connection=#<PG::Connection:0x007fa8b994fcf0 
              @socket_io=nil, @notice_receiver=nil, 
              @notice_processor=nil>>
```

When I do the query with two conditions

```
results = connection.execute("SELECT * 
                              FROM training_employees 
                              LEFT JOIN trainings 
                              ON training_employees.training_id = trainings.id 
                              WHERE trainings.date >='2014-06-29' 
                              AND trainings.date <='2014-06-30'")
results.each do |row|
  puts row
end
```

Only return this, not the records list as with one condition

```
 => #<PG::Result:0x007fa8b75c5398 
      @connection=#<PG::Connection:0x007fa8b994fcf0 @socket_io=nil, 
                    @notice_receiver=nil, @notice_processor=nil>>
```

I have tested the conditions individually and return what I expect(exists records between the date range)

These are my models

```
Training(id: integer, name: string, date: datetime, 
         expected_attendance: integer, created_at: datetime, 
         updated_at: datetime, service_company_id: integer) 
TrainingEmployee(id: integer, employee_id: integer, 
                 training_id: integer, created_at: 
                 datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

I'm using ruby 2.1.1 and Rails 4.1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're only actually getting **midnight** of the 30th.  When your types get converted for comparison, here's what your query actually looks like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM training_employees 
LEFT JOIN trainings 
       ON training_employees.training_id = trainings.id 
WHERE trainings.date >='2014-06-29 00:00:00.000000' 
      AND trainings.date <='2014-06-30 00:00:00.000000'
```

.... so of course no records from `trainings` with `date = "2014-06-30 02:43:00"` will be included.  The correct way to query date/time/timestamps is with an [exclusive upper bound](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) - that is, `trainings.date < '2014-07-01'`.

This also causes no records at all to be returned because you don't actually have a `LEFT JOIN`, you effectively have an `INNER JOIN`.  Here's why; when the `WHERE` clause rolls around, anything that *is* `LEFT JOIN`ed and has no records would make those conditions `null` and cause the db to exclude them.  If you actually want the `LEFT JOIN`, you need to move the conditions up to the `ON` clause.  If you actually do want an `INNER JOIN`, you should *still* move them up to the `ON` clause, as it makes the connection more obvious.

Aside: what does `trainings.date` actually represent?  That's a terribly ambiguous name...

Comment: trainings.date represent the date when a training is offered. Thanks!

Comment: @rcrivera - then it should be named something like `offered_On`, or `offered_At` (this one more likely if time information is included).  Generally, try to keep the type out of variable/column names.  (There are a few things that _seem_ to include this information, but don't quite, like `calendar_date` or `business_date`, where "date" is a concept that would be awkward to avoid).

Answer (score 0):

All the timestamps in your `date` are, in fact, greater than 2014-06-30 because all five of them are:

```
"date"=>"2014-06-30 02:43:00"
```

A date of `2014-06-30` would correspond to a timestamp of `2014-06-30 00:00:00` so the time-of-day components of your timestamps are interfering with your query logic.

The solution is to use a `date` column to store dates, not a timestamp. Then you won't have any timezone, time-of-day, ... issues.