# Ruby on Rails - How Do I Added a Where Clause to My Raw SQL Query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

In my Rails app, I have this scope which returns the `Articles` that have received the most views by joining the Ahoy Events table and my Articles table which is working.

```
  # article.rb
  scope :trending, (lambda do |time|
    joins("
      INNER JOIN (
        #{Ahoy::Event.where(time: time).to_sql}
      ) AS ahoy_events_by_time
      ON (ahoy_events_by_time.properties->>'id')::Integer = articles.id
    ")
    .select('articles.*, COUNT(ahoy_events_by_time.id) AS views_count')
    .group('articles.id')
    .order(Arel.sql("COUNT(#{count}) DESC"))
  end)

 # controller
 @articles = Article.trending(30.days.ago..Time.zone.now)
```

I want to do something similar for my `Submissions` now.  However, I want the scope to be include another attribute (submission.contest_id) to further limit the scope.

So I'm trying to edit this now to include `contest_id` so only the submissions for a given `Contest` show - so something like this:

`@submissions = Submission.trending(30.days.ago..Time.zone.now, @contest.id)`

```
     scope :trending, (lambda do |time|
        joins("
          INNER JOIN (
            #{Ahoy::Event.where(time: time).to_sql}
          ) AS ahoy_events_by_time
          ON (ahoy_events_by_time.properties->>'id')::Integer = submissions.id
        ")
        .select("submissions.*, COUNT(ahoy_events_by_time.id) AS views_count")
        .group('submissions.id')
        .order(Arel.sql("COUNT(#{count}) DESC"))
  end)
```

What I'd like to do now is pass in another value (@submission.contest_id) so only certain `Submissions` are included in the query.

So I'm trying to just pass in the `contest_id` as another param:

`@submissions = Submission.trending(30.days.ago..Time.zone.now, @contest.id)`

However, I'm doing something wrong because once I try to add contest_id, two things are incorrect.

1. It no longer shows all of the submissions that have that contest_id (if I simply do @submissions = @contest.submissions instead of the trending scope, it shows all of them).
2. It isn't returning the submissions returned according to the view count (it's not in the correct order)

I've looked at this SO question: [Rails Raw SQL WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592518/rails-raw-sql-where-clause)

And I've tried changing the scope to:

```
# this results in not all submissions being returned, and an incorrect sort order
  scope :trending, (lambda do |time, contest_id|
    joins("
      INNER JOIN (
        #{Ahoy::Event.where(time: time).to_sql}
      ) AS ahoy_events_by_time
      ON (ahoy_events_by_time.properties->>'id')::Integer = submissions.id
    ")
    .select("submissions.*, COUNT(ahoy_events_by_time.id) AS views_count")
    .where(contest_id: contest_id)
    .group('submissions.id')
    .order(Arel.sql("COUNT(#{count}) DESC"))
  end)

    # this gets a syntax error PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
    # LINE 1: SELECT submissions.* WHERE(contest_id = 2), COUNT(ahoy_event...
    
    scope :trending, (lambda do |time, contest_id|
        joins("
          INNER JOIN (
            #{Ahoy::Event.where(time: time).to_sql}
          ) AS ahoy_events_by_time
          ON (ahoy_events_by_time.properties->>'id')::Integer = submissions.id
        ")
        .select("submissions.* WHERE(contest_id = #{contest_id}), COUNT(ahoy_events_by_time.id) AS views_count")
        .where(contest_id: contest_id)
        .group('submissions.id')
        .order(Arel.sql("COUNT(#{count}) DESC"))
      end)

    # I've tried adjusting the commas (to put one before `WHERE`, and to also remove all commas so it reads like `submissions.* WHERE(contest_id = #{contest_id}) COUNT(ahoy_events_by_time.id)`, but the syntax is incorrect still.
```

I've tried looking through the Rails Guides, I could figure out the right way to write this in the Active Record Query Interface Guide (I couldn't find another guide that dealt with querying the DB).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this after the .select

```
  .where("submissions.contest_id = ?", contest_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You somehow painted too much of everything, which is quite difficult to trace your final task. I assume you wanted something like this:

```rb
  scope :trending, (lambda do |time, contest_id|
    joins("
      INNER JOIN (
        #{Ahoy::Event.where(time: time).to_sql}
      ) AS ahoy_events_by_time
      ON (ahoy_events_by_time.properties->>'id')::Integer = submissions.id
    ")
    .select("submissions.*, COUNT(ahoy_events_by_time.id) AS views_count")
    .where(submissions: { contest_id: contest_id })
    .group('submissions.id')
    .order(Arel.sql("COUNT(#{count}) DESC"))
  end)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  If you let me know what other info would be helpful, I'll add it.  This code seems to also only return one of the three `@contest.submissions`.  What I'm trying to do is just order all of the `@contest.submissions` based on how many views each of the submissions#show page got (using the `ahoy_events` table).

Comment: Examine all parts of the query one by one, and find the fragment whose addition ceases to return the result you expect. For me personally, it's strange, for example, that your id should coincide with some period of time. Also that the PG does not issue an error on `select submissions.*`, since only participates in the grouping `submissions.id`, it already looks more like MySQL and not PostgreSQL